# Definition of confirm() function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know how does confirm function works in javascript. What is source code of confirm function? How javascript pause the execution of any function till click on any button? Confirm function return  true if click on "ok" and return false if click on cancel button? I want to create similar confirm box in bootstrap modal. Can i..? Please help me. I have searched lot but didn't get answer.

Comment: You can create your own confirm box using promises or by using a callback, you'd find a lot of useful information if you just googled what you want to do though

Comment: actually I want to understand how confirm return true or false. It mean that how it pause execution till click on button.

Comment: Confirm is a system function. You cannot implement its behaviour in js.

Comment: ok ok. Thank you so much. Actually I want to create pop up like confirm using  bootstrap. So I want to understand implementation of it.